# what if workgroup has more than 20 computers

Tags: windows, networking, dns, video-streaming, workgroup

I have about 120 computers at my workgroup !
we started with 17 pcs then the network grow with the company
so we have now more than 120 computers in the same workGroup !

my question is may this affect the performance of the network
as file transfer or else
????
my main need is to speedup files playing through network
as videos.

1- the use of workgroup on more than 120 computers may affect network performance ?
2- its better to use domain controller?
3- if Iam using Domain controller the network will be faster especially file transfer ?

thank you.